# Javascript get og:image image from iframe (video link)

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

I'm trying to get the og:image from iframe (strem video links)
example: to get the og:image i have this PHP Code

```
<?php
$tags = get_meta_tags('https://streamango.com/embed/lmstprreclrdfmrn/');  
echo $tags['og:image'];
?>
```

but i need it with Javascipt, so I'm trying to get the og:image from chrome extension, so i need this function

1. get the link from iframe (not direct from web)
2. from iframe link get the og:image
   and show it example with PHP `echo $tags['og:image']` but with Javascript i don't have any idea how to show it, maybe is too much to ask this, but I can find a solution. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
 [images captured via a video element and a canvas element](http://cwestblog.com/2017/05/03/javascript-snippet-get-video-frame-as-an-image/)